# python gpg decrypt resulting in empty file sometimes

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, google-cloud-functions, gnupg

Trying to automate file decryption in cloud function using python3.9 from GCS and then upload it to another GCS bucket.
The problem is inconsistent decryption result where file might be empty with cloud function marked as success and when I delete and reupload the same file, the file is decrypted with no problem.

[failed result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoUOp.png)

this is the code I use to decrypt the file

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import glob
import logging as log
from google.cloud import storage
from subprocess import PIPE
from pathlib import Path

def data_decrypt (data,context):
    if Path(data['name']).suffix.lower() == '.pgp':
        input_filename = data['name'].split('/')[-1]
        file_name = input_filename.split('.')[0]
        input_path = f'/tmp/{input_filename}'
        print(input_filename)

        outdir_path = f'/tmp/decrypt'
        os.makedirs(outdir_path, exist_ok=True)
        storage_client = storage.Client()
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(data['bucket'])
        bucket_target = storage_client.get_bucket(os.environ['bucket_proc'])
        bucket_key = storage_client.get_bucket(os.environ['bucket_key'])
        blob = bucket.get_blob(data['name'])
        blob.download_to_filename(input_path)
        blobkey = bucket_key.get_blob("key.asc")
        blobkey.download_to_filename("/tmp/key.asc")
        print(bucket_target)

        cmd1 = f'gpg --batch --import /tmp/key.asc'
        cmd = f'gpg --decrypt --ignore-mdc-error --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase [my_passphrase] "{input_path}">"{outdir_path}/{file_name}.csv"'
        print(cmd1)
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        print(cmd)
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        process.wait()
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

        outfolder = f'{outdir_path}/{file_name}.csv'
        blob2 = bucket_target.blob(f'{file_name}.csv')
        blob2.upload_from_filename(outfolder)
```

tried to change the process variable as the comment suggest but still resulting in 0bytes file

```
cmd1 = f'gpg --batch --import /tmp/key.asc'
cmd = f'gpg --decrypt --ignore-mdc-error --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase xlaxiata "{input_path}">"{outdir_path}/{file_name}.csv"'
print(cmd1)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
process.wait()
print(cmd)
process1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
process1.wait()
```

Comment: It looks like you overwrite the variable `process` holding the first `Process`object with the result of the second `subprocess.Popen`. These processes run in parallel, but it looks like they should run sequentially, though I'm not sure. You certainly lose standard output and standard error from the first process.

Comment: tried your suggestion and modify the code
`cmd1 = f'gpg --batch --import /tmp/key.asc'
        cmd = f'gpg --decrypt --ignore-mdc-error --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase xlaxiata "{input_path}">"{outdir_path}/{file_name}.csv"'
        print(cmd1)
        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        process.wait()
        print(cmd)
        process1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
        process1.wait()`
stil resulting in 0bytes file @PresidentJamesK.Polk